# Regular expression for hashtags and colors

Tags: jquery, regex, hex, hashtag

I am using this code for finding hashtags in my text and replace them with a link. However , my text passages also include hex colors. So whenever i parse the code, my color spans get replaced with the link. Is there a way how to prevent this.

```
hashtag_regexp = /#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

function linkHashtags(text) {
 return text.replace(
    hashtag_regexp,
    '<a  href="'+base_url+'home/getTagArticles/$1">#$1</a>'
 );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.article-text').each(function() {
    $(this).html(linkHashtags($(this).html()));
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the hex colors with their context? That should show what you need to match to avoid hitting them.

Comment: What is `#$1` expected to return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/((?!(#[a-fA-F0-9]{3})(\W|$)|(#[a-fA-F0-9]{6})(\W|$))#[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/g
```

This will look for all alphanumeric hashtags and ignore any 3 or 6 character hashtags that are hexbased when they are followed by a non alpha numberic character or a line ending. It's not the smoothest, but I tested it and it seems to work.

```
#aaa  //no match
#ffffff  //no match
#ffffff.  //no match
#rat  //match
#HashtagHere  //match
```

EDIT: I edited the regex to account for line endings as the end of colors too.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is identify something about the context of the hex colors that is distinct, then add that to the regex as a [negative-lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead).

Assuming they are used for background colors in inline CSS, like this:

```
background-color: #a4d6FF
```

your regex could be modified as follows:

```
hashtag_regexp = /(?!background-color: *)#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;
```

(not tested; let me know if it works)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    var hashtag_regexp = /(#(?!\d+|\w+))/;
    var base_url = "/abc123/";

    function linkHashtags(_, text) {
     // note `$1` will return `#` as the remembered matched substring
     return text.replace(
        hashtag_regexp,
        '<a  href="'+base_url+'home/getTagArticles/$1">$1</a>'
     );
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.article-text').each(function() {
        $(this).html(linkHashtags);
      });
    });
```

```js
var hashtag_regexp = /(#(?!\d+|\w+))/;
var base_url = "/abc123/";

function linkHashtags(_, text) {
 return text.replace(
    hashtag_regexp,
    '<a  href="'+base_url+'home/getTagArticles/$1">$1</a>'
 );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.article-text').each(function() {
    $(this).html(linkHashtags);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="article-text">
# #000000
</span>
<span class="article-text">
# #000033
</span>
<span class="article-text">
# #0000aa
</span>
<span class="article-text">
# #0000a3
</span>
```